# Escaping ampersands in Windows batch files

Tags: windows, batch-file, escaping

I realise that you can escape ampersands in batch files using the hat character

e.g.

```
echo a ^& b
a & b
```

But I'm using the command

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%A IN ('DIR /B /A-D /S .acl') DO ProcessACL.cmd "%%A"
```

which is finding all the files named '.acl' in the current directory, or a subdirectory of the current directory.

The problem is, I'm finding path names that include the '&' character (and no, they can't be renamed), and I need a way of automatically escaping the ampersands and calling the second batch file with the escaped path as the parameter.

```
rem ProcessACL.cmd
echo %1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is not the escaping, it seems to be in the second script.

If there is a line like

```
echo %1
```

Then it is expands and fails:

```
echo You & me.acl
```

Better to use delayed expansion like

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "var=%~1"
echo !var!
```

To avoid also problems with exclamation points `!` in the parameter, the first `set` should be used in a `DisableDelayedExpansion` context.

```
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "var=%~1"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo !var!
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for line should be (note the *.acl)

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%A IN ('DIR /B /A-D /S *.acl') DO ProcessACL.cmd "%%A"
```

ProcessACL.cmd can access the path passed to it with %1.

```
// ProcessACL.cmd
ECHO %1
```

Whatever is contained by the variable %1 is fully contained. There is no need for escapes. Escapes are for the batch processor to interpret the characters it is parsing.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The '.acl' is specifically looking for a file called '.acl', not all files with the extension of .acl. I'm already using %1 in the ProcessACL.cmd file, and this produces the error "& was unexpected at this time", when %1 contains a path that includes an ampersand.