# From command line on win7, how do I launch a process as administrator with elevated UAC

Tags: command-line, process, batch-file, admin, uac

I have a program which requires Administrative privileges that I want to run from a batch file. What command can I run from command line will run my program with administrative privileges? I'm okay with the pop-up window asking for permission. Additionally, the file needs to be able to run from anywhere on a computer so additional files are run from ./src. The problem is that if I right-click and choose "run as administrator" it changes my current directory so ./src no longer works. If I disable UAC on my machine then everything runs fine. Thank you!

Comment: Why not changing the path back to the batch file location? Ex `pushd "%~dp0"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I auto-elevate my batch file, so that it requests from UAC admin rights if required?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044985/how-can-i-auto-elevate-my-batch-file-so-that-it-requests-from-uac-admin-rights)

Answer (score 0):

Look here: https://superuser.com/a/269750/139371

[elevate](http://code.kliu.org/misc/elevate/) seems to be working, calling

```
C:\Utils\bin.x86-64\elevate.exe -k dir
```

executes `dir` in the "current directory" where `elevate` was called.

Answer (score 0):

This is tough, Microsoft provides no utility to do this (mostly because giving a batch file that ability breaks security), except for RunAs, and that requires that the Administrator account be activated.

There IS a JScript program that can do something similar, by using SendKeys to open the Start menu and type cmd[CTL]+[SHIFT]+[ENTER] which will launch a Command-Line shell.

Save the following as as .js file, like StartAdmin.js:

```
var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys("^{esc}cmd^+{ENTER}");   The equivilent of [CTRL]+[ESC] cmd [CTRL]+[SHIFT]+[ENTER]
```

To run StartAdmin.js from a batch file, you will need the following line:

```
wscript StartAdmin.js
```

To launch from a particular directory and launch a batch file, change line 2 in StartAdmin.js to something like:

```
WshShell.SendKeys("^{esc}cmd /C "cd %userprofile% & batchfile.bat"^+{ENTER}");
```

/C switch tells it to run the commands, then close the command-line window.
/K would leave the command window open after it exited the batch file.
To help you understand the SendKeys commands:

```
+=[Shift Key]
^=[Control Key]
{esc}=[Escape Key]
{enter}=[Enter Key]
```

To learn more about using CMD.EXE, type CMD /? at the command prompt.

This is a very untidy and ugly way to do it, but it's the only way I know how using only the tools that come with Windows.