# Change system PATH permanently with node.js on windows?

Tags: node.js

I created a little script that download and install python3 silently on Windows.

The problem is that I need to launch CMD as admin before using `node myfile.js`.

Is this a way to ask people to execute as admin in the beginning of the nodejs script?

I also need a way to change the system PATH to add python PATH permanently.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the world of installers.

**1** Official Microsoft's answer is use the [Windows Installer (*.msi)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer). Windows will run it and take care of the elevated access rights automatically.

You can create MSI scripts using free tools like [WiX Toolset](http://wixtoolset.org).

**2** If you don't want to go the steep official way and still want a decent support for operations like changing the system PATH then Jordan Russel's [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) is very powerful free install builder that can be programmed to do nearly anything using the built-in Pascal script.

**3** You can of course do it your way using a little scripts and hitting all the obstacles again. It is certainly possible, some answers are available here on Stack Overflow, e.g.

- [Programmatically modifiy environment variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121795/programmatically-modifiy-environment-variables)
- [From command line on win7, how do I launch a process as administrator with elevated UAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510484/from-command-line-on-win7-how-do-i-launch-a-process-as-administrator-with-eleva)

Answer (score 0):

I found a very simple solution:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec('setx /m PATH "%PATH%;c:\\DevTools\\python3"');
```