# how to establish an ad-hoc wifi connection in windows 8

Tags: windows-8

I connect all my devices by creating an ad-hoc wifi connection in my laptop but windows 8 does not seems to have an option for ad-hoc connection. 
Please help me out , i have tried 3rd party software "Connectify" which does not seems to work.

Comment: Stackoverflow is a programming questions site. This question belongs at www.superuser.com for your information!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just run the batch file to setup Adhoc using the builtin `netsh` utility ...

In order to use ICS (Internet Connection Sharing) feature, you need to turn on **sharing**.

To do so you have press ...

- `WinKey+R` and then type `ncpa.cpl`
- Right-click on the Wireless Network Adapter (the one from which you get internet) select `Properties` and then select the `Sharing` tab on top
- **check/mark** the `Allow other network users to connect through this computer's Internet connection`. From menu of Home Networking connection select Hosted Virtual Network that you created (**Local Area Connection * 12**). Click **OK** to save the configuration.

If in any case the DHCP is not running or working, you can put manual IP address setting on the Hosted Virtual Network Adapter (**Local Area Connection * 12**) ...

- IP Address: 192.168.137.2 (can vary)
- Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
- Default gateway: 192.168.137.1
- DNS: 8.8.8.8

Below is the batch file code, copy paste in notepad and save it with .cmd extension ...

Part of source code: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12264592/1420274)

```bsh
    @echo off
    CLS

    :checkPrivileges 
    NET FILE 1>NUL 2>NUL
    if '%errorlevel%' == '0' ( goto gotPrivileges ) else ( goto getPrivileges ) 

    :getPrivileges 
    if '%1'=='ELEV' (shift & goto gotPrivileges)  

    setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
    set "batchPath=%~0"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    ECHO Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs" 
    ECHO UAC.ShellExecute "!batchPath!", "ELEV", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs" 
    "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs" 
    exit /B

    :gotPrivileges 
    setlocal & pushd .

    REM Run shell as admin (example) - put here code as you like
    ECHO.
    ECHO ============================
    ECHO Setting up Adhoc Network ...
    ECHO ============================
    netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=LocalAdHoc key=password
    netsh wlan start hostednetwork

    cmd /k
```

You can stop the network using the following command

```
    netsh wlan stop hostednetwork
```

Comment: Giving Following Error : The hosted network couldn't be started.
The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested opera
tion.

Comment: Probably your wireless device is not properly installed or is disabled.

Comment: Do yo uknow of an easy way to manage the dhcp assignment, or configure a range of ip's the ad-hoc network will assign? (I really only have one device connecting, and I want it to always have the same IP)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `netsh` utility to do this. Here is a good and complete tutorial to do what you want :

> http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-create-wireless-ad-hoc-internet-connection-in-windows-8/

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8 adHoc Connection Creator. Its a free GUI utility to create an adhoc connection in windows 8. you can also modify the progrm under the license term. please visit https://adhoc8.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

use this simple tool to create wifi adhoc networks in windows 8......

http://www.softpedia.com/get/Network-Tools/Misc-Networking-Tools/Wi-MAN.shtml

Answer (score 0):

As gentlemen said You have to use the netsh utility to do this. But there is a graphical tool to do that and it simulates the "netsh" command, and it is free.
you can find it here:
https://www.facebook.com/AdHocInitializer