# Run as administrator from the command line

Tags: batch-file, admin, uac

To help my computer boot faster, I created a simple batch file that will open the programs I want, rather than do it all on startup, when I sometimes don't want them to.

```
@ECHO OFF

cd "C:\Users\Aaron\Documents\Documents"
start SSS.lnk

cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\puush"
start puush.exe

cd "C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Roaming\Google\Google Talk\"
start googletalk.exe

cd "C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Facebook\Messenger\2.1.4651.0\"
start FacebookMessenger.exe

cd "C:\Program Files\Synergy\"
start synergy.exe

cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\"
start Skype.exe

cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Miranda IM\"
start miranda32.exe
```

However,

```
cd "C:\Users\Aaron\Documents\Documents"
start SSS.lnk
```

is a service that's set to `Manual`, and I start that myself, and it requires to be run as administrator to start. Is there anything to add in front of that to run just that as administrator?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I auto-elevate my batch file, so that it requests from UAC admin rights if required?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044985/how-can-i-auto-elevate-my-batch-file-so-that-it-requests-from-uac-admin-rights)

Answer (score 4):

You might wish to have a look at *[Runas](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525%28WS.10%29.aspx)*.

Short answer: You can use runas.exe:

```
C:\>runas /user:<localmachinename>\administrator cmd
```

or

```
runas.exe /user:administrator "full qualified path to your exe"
```

For the last cmd, you can add `/savecred` to save the administrator's password (not that I'm saying this is a good idea).

Comment: Okay. Now if I wanted to combine that with "cd "C:\Users\Aaron\Documents\Documents"
start SSS.lnk" ?

Comment: `runas.exe /user:administrator "start C:\Users\Aaron\Documents\Documents\SSS.lnk"` should do the trick

Comment: http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/win8/windows8-administrator-activate.htm - you can also replace user:administrator with a user having admin rights.

Comment: Right. I changed it to my login "email@gmail.com" and now I get: RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - start C:\Users\Aaron\Documents\Documents\SSS.lnk
2: The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: I changed it to runas.exe /user:talormanda@gmail.com "C:\Users\Aaron\Documents\Documents\SynergyService.bat" it is suppose to start a service but it failed. It will launch .exe 's however, but they are not being run as admin.

Comment: Are you asking if you can bypass the UAC prompt? You can't. That's the whole point of having UAC in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Workaround: Create a shortcut to your script. Go to properties, shortcut, advanced. Check "run as administrator".

There you go; every time you access via shortcut it will open as administrator.

Comment: I came here to write this as answer :) This works like charm. Most answers think of _runas_ which asks password. This is the way to go about it without knowing Admin password.

Answer (score 0):

There some misunderstoods:

1. How to get localmachinename

   There are many ways, some of them are:

   a. `c:\>hostname` or

   b. `c:\>echo  %computername%`
2. You can't use `runas [...]` command if you don't have set password to your Windows.

   `1327: Logon failure: user account restriction. Possible reasons are blank passwords not allowed, logon hour restrictions, or a policy restriction has been enforced.`