# Batch file - Run as administrator, if not delete batch file?

Tags: batch-file, uac, administrator, elevated-privileges

Hi I have made a batch file which I need to run as administrator. For that purpose I use this script, which I took from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12264592/1016343) (StackOverflow).

But what I want, is if the user choose not to run as administrator (click NO to UAC), then the program will exit, and the batch will delete it selves automatically.

The command for the batch file to delete it selves is "del %0", but I need help as to where in this script, I can put this command.
I tried to put it with "@exit /B", but then the batch file will delete if you press either YES or NO to UAC, and then the rest of the batch file cannot execute

Anybody can help figure out how to only run the command "del %0", when a user press "NO" to UAC?

---

```
@echo off
:checkPrivileges 
NET FILE 1>NUL 2>NUL
if '%errorlevel%' == '0' ( goto gotPrivileges ) else ( goto getPrivileges ) 

:getPrivileges 
if '%1'=='ELEV' (shift & goto gotPrivileges) 

setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "batchPath=%~0"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
ECHO Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs" 
ECHO UAC.ShellExecute "!batchPath!", "ELEV", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs" 
"%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs" 
@exit /B 

:gotPrivileges
```

---

Thanks guys
Rune

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you need a way to detect if the UAC prompt was canceled. You can detect this if you use my Elevate32.exe or Elevate64.exe (download [ElevationToolkit1.zip](http://www.westmesatech.com/misctools.html)) program with the -w option, which will return an exit code of 1223 (ERROR_CANCELLED) if you cancel the UAC prompt.

Bill

Comment: Is there a way to do this without your software?

Comment: I doubt it would be simple to do without an external executable. The external tool shouldn't be an impediment since it's freeware.

Comment: Assuming that you have permission to download software.

Comment: Yes, that can depend on the organization. However, in my experience, if the tool fits the need and is free, it is often the case that it can be vetted by security and permitted for use.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but it's still useful to have a solution posted.
If you have Powershell installed you don't need to create a new vbs script and the ERRORLEVEL can be checked to detect if the UAC prompt was canceled or not.

Just put this in your script:

```
@echo off
:checkPrivileges 
NET FILE 1>NUL 2>NUL
if '%errorlevel%' == '0' ( goto gotPrivileges 
) else ( powershell "saps -filepath %0 -verb runas" >nul 2>&1)
if NOT '%errorlevel%' == '0' call :deleteSelf
exit /b


:deleteSelf
start /b "" cmd /c del "%~f0"&exit /b



REM No need for this label
::getPrivileges 
::if '%1'=='ELEV' (shift & goto gotPrivileges) 

::setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
::set "batchPath=%~0"
::setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
::ECHO Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs" 
::ECHO UAC.ShellExecute "!batchPath!", "ELEV", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs" 
::"%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs" 
::@exit /B 

:gotPrivileges
```

The delete method I took from dbenham's post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20329355/how-to-make-a-batch-file-delete-itself)