# How to ask for administrator privileges in a Windows Batch script?

Tags: batch-file, privileges, administrator

I have a Windows Batch script and I want it to ask for administrator privileges before executing the commands inside it. How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I auto-elevate my batch file, so that it requests from UAC admin rights if required?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044985/how-can-i-auto-elevate-my-batch-file-so-that-it-requests-from-uac-admin-rights)

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Provoke elevation from a WSH script, like documented in the blog post [Scripting Elevation on Vista](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaron_margosis/archive/2007/07/01/scripting-elevation-on-vista.aspx).
2. Use an external executable that provokes the UAC prompt, such as [Elevate32.exe/Elevate64.exe](http://www.westmesatech.com/misctools.html).

For your scenario, #2 may be preferable because you can detect whether the elevation prompt was canceled (exit code 1223) and you can also wait for the launched executable to finish before continuing (-w parameter).

Bill