# Run batch as Admin (auto-elevate) and then de-elevate

Tags: windows, perl, batch-file, command-prompt

I have a script that runs in 2 parts. The first part requires admin access (updates HOSTS file and does some copying/overwriting). After that part finishes, I need to map a drive using the hostname alias the first part of the script updated.

I have figured out how to get the elevated privileges by using this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044985/how-can-i-auto-elevate-my-batch-file-so-that-it-requests-from-uac-admin-rights). But mapping a drive (while in admin) maps a drive into the admin's session. I need to "de-elevate" back into user mode to run my second script.

This is a script I run at least once every day, and possibly multiple times per day. I am trying to create a solution that is just 1 .bat file, if possible. For reasons, the scripts are written in perl.

**Things I have tried:**

1. Using the runas /user:regular_user command (this does *not* work)
2. 1 bat file Using CALL for the 2 batch files (This "works" but for some reason both run at the same time)
3. Running 2 bat files separately, and manually.
4. Searching SO, but I could not find admin->user instead only user->admin

**TLDR:** *How do I de-elevate to user mode from admin mode in a batch file?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to use the best third party remote/local execution tool : Windows Sysinternals PSEXEC. You can supply credentials and accomplish what you need using PSEXEC! You can put PSEXEC commands into your batch file or vbs and have them run without a hitch. You can also call one command with PSEXEC elevated permission and the next without any elevation, while mixing credentials in a single unique batch file.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx

Comment: Cool, this sounds promising. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using 2 batch files, call the batch `ElevatedBatch.cmd` with elevation by using `Main.cmd` (which continues doing unelevated things):

```
@ECHO OFF
START /WAIT ElevatedBatch.cmd %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
REM here you can do unelevated stuff:
ECHO Running unelevated now
```

The parameter `/WAIT` ensures that the script will wait until `ElevatedBatch.cmd` has ended. For `ElevatedBatch.cmd`  you can use a template like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12264592/1016343) one to elevate it.

Answer (score 0):

Do first the non-elevated part, then elevate and continue.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible in the OP's scenario. OP says that he needs to update HOSTS file first, and then use new aliases to do the second part.