# Batch file to run under administrator always

Tags: batch-file, exe

How can i make a batch file always run as administrator and then convert it into exe file so that it asks the user to run as administrator in all computers

Comment: you can create a shortcut to it with an admin privileges...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of windows you are using - there are already answers on stack about this

[How can I auto-elevate my batch file, so that it requests from UAC administrator rights if required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044985/how-can-i-auto-elevate-my-batch-file-so-that-it-requests-from-uac-admin-rights)