# How to make a batch file tell if it is elevated or not

Tags: windows, batch-file, elevation, elevated-privileges

I need a code in the space below to tell if the batch file is elevated or not. I am making a program so that if it is elevated it does something one way and if it is not it does it the other way. Does anyone know a code I could use.

```
@echo off




:no
echo no
pause
goto exit
:yes
echo yes
pause
goto exit
:exit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend something based off of [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12264592/2101267):

```
@echo off

NET FILE 1>NUL 2>NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO no
GOTO yes

:no
echo no
pause
goto exit
:yes
echo yes
pause
goto exit
:exit
```

Answer (score 1):

Run some command which requires elevated privilege & check `ERRORLEVEL`

```
@echo off
at > nul

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0  goto elevated

REM do non-elevated stuff
goto end

:elevated
REM do elevated stuff

:end
```

Comment: Under Windows 10, the AT command has been deprecated and always returns errorlevel 1.  NET FILE still works though.