# Run a powershell script in batch file as administrator

Tags: batch-file, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a powershell script. To run this sript, I have written a batch file.
Here is code of batch file:

```
:: psscript.bat
set psscript='%CD%\Hotfix-Automation-Installer.ps1'

echo Running PowerShell Script: %psscript%
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe ^&%psscript% %*
```

When I double-click on batch file, I want my script Hotfix-Automation-Installer.ps1 to be run as an administrator.
How I can run this script as administrator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read Matt's article on this link:
[How can I auto-elevate my batch file, so that it requests from UAC administrator rights if required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044985/how-can-i-auto-elevate-my-batch-file-so-that-it-requests-from-uac-admin-rights)

He has given complete script to elevate from current session to administrator session. Quiet helpful.