# Starting a batch file from PowerShell with arguments

Tags: windows, batch-file, powershell, cmd, escaping

Based on [How can I auto-elevate my batch file, so that it requests from UAC administrator rights if required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044985/how-can-i-auto-elevate-my-batch-file-so-that-it-requests-from-uac-admin-rights) I'm trying to make an `RunElevated.bat` (see code below) that accepts a command-line (batch file name and parameters) as arguments.

The `RunElevated.bat` works fine when the target batch file path has no spaces in them. But it fails as soon as that path has spaces: no matter how I quote things, either PowerShell barfs, or the parameters are not passed correctly from PowerShell to the batch file.

I tried:

1. escaping with `""` (as [suggested by many sources](https://www.google.com/search?q=batch%20file%20escape%20double%20quotes))
2. escaping with `\"` (as suggested by [Escaping quotes in powershell.exe -command via command prompt](http://www.tinyint.com/index.php/2011/04/20/escaping-quotes-in-powershell-exe-command-via-command-prompt/))
3. adding `--%` (as suggested by [PowerShell and external commands done right](http://edgylogic.com/blog/powershell-and-external-commands-done-right/) and [Easier Reuse of Command Lines From Cmd.exe](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/06/14/new-v3-language-features.aspx))
4. surrounding with `'` (as [suggested by CB.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24736482/starting-a-batch-file-from-powershell-with-arguments?noredirect=1#comment38375072_24736482)).
   So:

   - Is what I want to do possible at all?
   - If so: how?

`RunElevated.bat`:

```
:checkParameters
  echo [%*]
  if [%1]==[] ( goto :help ) else ( goto :checkPrivileges )

:help
  echo Syntax:
  echo   %0 CmdLine
  echo Where CmdLine is executed with UAC privileges.
  goto :exit

:checkPrivileges 
  net file 1>nul 2>nul
  if '%errorlevel%' == '0' ( goto :gotPrivileges ) else ( goto :getPrivileges )

:getPrivileges
  PowerShell "Start-Process -FilePath \"%0\" -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList \"%*\""
  goto :exit

:gotPrivileges
  %*
  pause

:exit
  pause
  exit /b
```

`echo-cd.bat` which I stored in both `D:\tools\echo-cd.bat` and `"D:\to ols\echo-cd.bat"`:

```
echo Current Directory: [%CD%]
echo Parameters: [%*]
pause
```

## This runs fine:

```
D:\tools\RunElevated.bat D:\tools\echo-cd.bat foo
```

## These fail:

### `D:\tools\RunElevated.bat "D:\to ols\echo-cd.bat" foo`

First failure is at the `%*`:

```
C:\Windows\system32>D:\to ols\echo-cd.bat foo
'D:\to' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

This is because PowerShell removed the quotes around the batch file name:

```
C:\Windows\system32>echo [D:\to ols\echo-cd.bat foo]
[D:\to ols\echo-cd.bat foo]
```

I expected `D:\to ols\echo-cd.bat` to have double quotes around it, and `foo` not.

### `D:\tools\RunElevated.bat \"D:\to ols\echo-cd.bat\" foo`

Second failure is at the `PowerShell` level:

```
D:\>PowerShell "Start-Process -FilePath \"D:\tools\RunElevated.bat\" -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList \"\"D:\to ols\echo-cd.bat\" foo\""
Start-Process : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ArgumentList'. The argument is null or empty. Supply an argument that is not null or empty and then try the command again.
At line:1 char:77
+ Start-Process -FilePath "D:\tools\RunElevated.bat" -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList <<<<  ""D:\to ols\echo-cd.bat" foo"
```

This is because escaping twice will end up with an empty string for `ArgumentList`.

### `D:\tools\RunElevated.bat --% "D:\to ols\echo-cd.bat" foo`

Third failure is also at the `%*`:

```
C:\Windows\system32>--% D:\to ols\echo-cd.bat foo
'--%' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

This too is because PowerShell removed the quotes around the batch file name:

```
C:\Windows\system32>echo [--% D:\to ols\echo-cd.bat foo]
[--% D:\to ols\echo-cd.bat foo]
```

I expected `--%` to be absent, `D:\to ols\echo-cd.bat` to have double quotes around it, and `foo` not.

### `D:\tools\RunElevated.bat '"D:\to ols\echo-cd.bat"' foo`

Again a failure is at the `%*`:

```
C:\Windows\system32>'D:\to ols\echo-cd.bat' foo
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

This is because PowerShell removed the double quotes (and left the single quotes) around the batch file name:

```
C:\Windows\system32>echo ['D:\to ols\echo-cd.bat' foo]
['D:\to ols\echo-cd.bat' foo]

C:\Windows\system32>if ['D:\to] == [] (goto :help  )  else (goto :checkPrivileges  )
```

Comment: what about: `D:\tools\RunElevated.bat "'D:\to ols\echo-cd.bat\'" foo`?

Comment: @CB. that results in this error: `C:\Windows\system32>'D:\to ols\echo-cd.bat\' foo
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`. With the last backslash removed, I get `C:\Windows\system32>'D:\to ols\echo-cd.bat' foo
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

Comment: Yes sure... the last backslash was'nt would, forgot to delete it! Anyway try: `D:\tools\RunElevated.bat '"D:\to ols\echo-cd.bat"' foo`

Comment: @CB. that's the second error message in my above comment: it fails too (: I've added your suggestion to the list in my question for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

I recall using the following approach for this:

```
start "" %systemroot%\System32\windowspowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -exec bypass -noprofile -command "&{ start-process powershell -verb RunAs -ArgumentList '-noprofile -exec bypass -file \"c:\temp\test folder\elevatedpowershell.ps1\"'}"
```

You can replace \"c:\temp\test folder\elevatedpowershell.ps1\" with \"$0\" like you did there.
I also found the solution from Keith Hill on self elevating PowerShell to be useful if I need the person to be admin. I do not have the link now but it goes like this:

```
function IsAdministrator
{
    $Identity = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
    $Principal = New-Object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal($Identity)
    $Principal.IsInRole([System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)
}


function IsUacEnabled
{
    (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System).EnableLua -ne 0
}

if (!(IsAdministrator))
{
    if (IsUacEnabled)
    {
        [string[]]$argList = @('-NoProfile', '-File', ('"' + $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path + '"'))        
        $argList += $MyInvocation.BoundParameters.GetEnumerator() | Foreach {"-$($_.Key)", "$($_.Value)"}        
        $argList += $MyInvocation.UnboundArguments        
        Start-Process "$env:Windir\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe" -Verb Runas -WorkingDirectory $pwd -WindowStyle Hidden -ArgumentList $argList                        
        return
    }
    else
    {
        throw "You must be administrator to run this script"
    }
}
```

Assuming, you want to have elevated PowerShell script, you can have that at the top of your PowerShell script.

Comment: I'll try to test these somewhere later. For now I've just removed an special characters from the directory trees I inherited to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly but it can do the job.

Use single quotes (or any character of your choice) and insert this in your code:

```
:gotPrivileges
  cd "%~p0"
  set arg=%*
  set arg=%arg:'="%
  %arg%

::  %*
  pause
```

Comment: Thanks. It means loosing the single quote for other means, so I might do this with another character.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 8.3 file names enabled you can try this:

```
:getPrivileges
  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  set Args=%*
  for %%a in (%*) do if exist %%a (
            set Args=!Args:%%a="%%~sa"!
            )
  PowerShell "Start-Process -FilePath \"%0\" -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList \"%Args%\"" 2>nul
  goto :exit
```

However, if you pass an argument that happens to be the name of a file or folder (that exists relative to RunElevated.bat) it can get altered.