# Elevated batch script causing firefox to crash

Tags: windows, batch-file, uac, elevated-privileges

I was using Matt's idea over here. The only changes I made was adding the two netstat commands at the bottom and removed `cmd /k` since that seemed to make the script freeze. This script is causing firefox to crash. Can I please get some ideas on how and why this is happening? How do I fix this?

[How can I auto-elevate my batch file, so that it requests from UAC administrator rights if required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044985/how-can-i-auto-elevate-my-batch-file-so-that-it-requests-from-uac-administrator/12264592#12264592)

```
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Automatically check & get admin rights
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
@echo off
CLS
ECHO.
ECHO =============================
ECHO Running Admin shell
ECHO =============================

:checkPrivileges
NET FILE 1>NUL 2>NUL
if '%errorlevel%' == '0' ( goto gotPrivileges ) else ( goto getPrivileges )

:getPrivileges
if '%1'=='ELEV' (shift & goto gotPrivileges)
ECHO.
ECHO **************************************
ECHO Invoking UAC for Privilege Escalation
ECHO **************************************

setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "batchPath=%~0"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
ECHO Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs"
ECHO UAC.ShellExecute "!batchPath!", "ELEV", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs"
"%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs"
exit /B

:gotPrivileges
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::START
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
setlocal & pushd .

REM Run shell as admin (example) - put here code as you like
net stop "Audiosrv"
net start "Audiosrv"
```

Comment: What does this script have to do with Firefox?

Comment: Is there anything else going on on your machine? I ran this script with Firefox open and Firefox stayed open the whole time.

Comment: @jpw No idea. Thats why I'm so confused. I just know I use firefox ALL the time and whenever I run the script it crashes firefox.

Comment: @SomethingDark I have several windows explorer windows open, matlab, notepad++, a cmd window, adobe reader, and regular microsoft notepad open.