# what does a bang character mean in a windows bat file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to correct a bat file that uses bang characters where I would have expected some form of quote:
something like

```
set some_var=!some_var:"=\"!
```

and then later

```
some command !some_var!
```

It looks like the first is prompting for input with echo disabled, like prompting for a password, and the second referencing the variable. Normally, bat files use percent characters for that, like

```
%some_var%
```

Anyone know what the bang character does in a bat file exactly? Trying to debug this thing, and don't like guessing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From `cmd /?`:

> If delayed environment variable expansion is enabled, then the
>   exclamation character can be used to substitute the value of an
>   environment variable at execution time.

(The `cmd` help describes elsewhere various methods of enabling delayed environment variable expansion.)

And from `set /?`:

> Delayed environment variable expansion allows you to use a different
>   character (the exclamation mark) to expand environment variables at
>   execution time.

And

> Environment variable substitution has been enhanced as follows:
>
> ```
> %PATH:str1=str2%
> ```
>
> would expand the PATH environment variable, substituting each occurrence
>   of "str1" in the expanded result with "str2".

Your case of `set some_var=!some_var:"=\"!` is therefore updating `some_var` to replace `"` characters with `\"`.