# How to get admin privilege in cmd for running sc.exe?

Tags: windows, batch-file, service, cmd

I have created a batch file for starting a service using sc.exe. But it asks for admin privilege while running. Is there is any code that can be used in batch file to elevate cmd to admin level?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I auto-elevate my batch file, so that it requests from UAC administrator rights if required?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044985/how-can-i-auto-elevate-my-batch-file-so-that-it-requests-from-uac-administrator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
@echo off
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"
if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 (GOTO askAdmin)
GOTO gotAdmin


:askAdmin
::batch is being ran as normal user
echo I'm not an admin yet
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
echo Requesting administrative privileges...
goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )
:UACPrompt
echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
"%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
exit /B


:gotAdmin
if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ( del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" )
pushd "%CD%"
CD /D "%~dp0"
::batch is being ran as admin
echo Now I'm an admin!
pause
```

Comment: I used this but it is asking permission in between execution. Is it possible to avoid this situation..i.e, run cmd as admin without asking permission,

Comment: @shijin you can run it as admin from the start by right clicking on it or using the shortcut mentioned in the other answer, but this is the only way to do it in the program itself

Comment: Is there is any way to get admin privilege from code itself? Without clicking run as admin?

Comment: @shijin That is what the code I provided does. However, it would be weird if a program could give itself admin priviliges without needing to ask for them. That would be a huge security threat, imagine a virus giving itself admin rights without needing confirmation from you.

Comment: my project is a forensic project. the project is to acquire the ram dump directly while plugging in a usb drive. while dumping there should be minimal user interactions.

Answer (score 0):

Press `Windows Key + X` and click `Command Prompt (Admin)`. Click yes if the user control center ask for permission

Comment: What if they're using a version of Windows before Windows 8?

Comment: I just try it in windows 8.

Comment: I know. Win+X is not a valid shortcut in Windows 7 or earlier, so this might not help some people.

Comment: Ah yes. and shijin just ask for code. I didn't see it. This may not the answer :)

Comment: I am trying to run a code from batch file. Is it possible to run cmd as admin without doing this?

Comment: Is there is any code for running cmd as admin without asking for permission?