# How run batch script to get output in text file

Tags: batch-file

Below executable return string values in command but when i execute below batch script it pop up different command line console and exits hence i am not getting any values in output.txt

how to capture this result ?

```
c:\ 
cd C:\Windows\System32  
start usbinvoke.exe argument >c:\result\outpput.txt
pause
```

Comment: Try `start usbinvoke.exe argument >> output.txt`

Comment: @JohnKens i tried with ">>c:\result\output.txt" and "> c:\result\output.txt" but both give empty file not out put of usb invoke since its launching command line seperately.

Comment: If you dwant to stick to `start`, try with `start "" /B ...`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
c:\ 
cd C:\Windows\System32  
usbinvoke.exe argument >c:\result\output.txt
pause
```

`start` does not wait unless you use `/wait` argument. Suggest remove `start` and just run the executable.

You cannot redirect streams with a process that does not wait as the no handle is attached to the process.

If you require `start` then use arguments `/b` (same window) and `/w` (same as `/wait`).

Comment: You can shift rightclick and run as admin. Internally handled, try the answer [How to get admin privilege in cmd for running sc.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35030154/how-to-get-admin-privilege-in-cmd-for-running-sc-exe).

Answer (score 3):

```
usbinvoke.exe argument > C:\result\output.txt
```

`Start` starts programs in unusual ways. See `start /?`

See [Command to run a .bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030190/command-to-run-a-bat-file)

Your other commands are unnecessary.

You right click a shortcut to cmd and tick Run As Administrator on the compatibility tab