# Call a .cmd file as admin

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, cmd

I have a VBScript which calls a .cmd file, but I need it to call it to run as administrator.

This is my code:

```
Dim shell
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell.Run "PapercutInstallprinter.cmd"
```

How can I edit that to force it to run as admin, and if needed ask the user for UAC elevation?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`ShellExecute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method to run external commands with elevated privileges:

```
Set app = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
app.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "PapercutInstallprinter.cmd", "", "runas", 1
```

Note that the new process will be started asynchronously, i.e. the call returns immediately without waiting for the external process to finish. Depending on what else your VBScript is doing you may need to add some waiting routine.

Answer (score 0):

You right click and chose Run As Administrator. This script  (with built in help) does the same as right clicking something and choosing a verb.

```
HelpMsg = vbcrlf & "  ShVerb" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "  David Candy 2014" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "  Lists or runs an explorer verb (right click menu) on a file or folder" & vbcrlf  & vbcrlf & "    ShVerb <filename> [verb]" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "  Used without a verb it lists the verbs available for the file or folder" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf
HelpMsg = HelpMsg & "  The program lists most verbs but only ones above the first separator" & vbcrlf & "  of the menu work when used this way" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf 
HelpMsg = HelpMsg & "  The Properties verb can be used. However the program has to keep running" & vbcrlf & "  to hold the properties dialog open. It keeps running by displaying" & vbcrlf & "  a message box." 
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set Ag = WScript.Arguments 
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If Ag.count = 0 then 
        wscript.echo "  ShVerb - No file specified"
        wscript.echo HelpMsg 
        wscript.quit
    Else If Ag.count = 1 then 
        If LCase(Replace(Ag(0),"-", "/")) = "/h" or Replace(Ag(0),"-", "/") = "/?" then 
            wscript.echo HelpMsg 
            wscript.quit
        End If
    ElseIf Ag.count > 2 then 
        wscript.echo vbcrlf & "  ShVerb - To many parameters" & vbcrlf & "  Use quotes around filenames and verbs containing spaces"  & vbcrlf
        wscript.echo HelpMsg 
        wscript.quit
    End If

    If fso.DriveExists(Ag(0)) = True then
        Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(fso.GetFileName(Ag(0)))
'       Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(fso.GetFileName(Ag(0)))
        Set objFolderItem = objFolder.self
        msgbox ag(0)
    ElseIf fso.FolderExists(Ag(0)) = True then
        Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(fso.GetParentFolderName(Ag(0)))
        Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(fso.GetFileName(Ag(0)))
    ElseIf fso.fileExists(Ag(0)) = True then
        Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(fso.GetParentFolderName(Ag(0)))
        Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(fso.GetFileName(Ag(0)))
    Else
        wscript.echo "  ShVerb - " & Ag(0) & " not found"
        wscript.echo HelpMsg 
        wscript.quit
    End If

    Set objVerbs = objFolderItem.Verbs

    'If only one argument list verbs for that item

    If Ag.count = 1 then
        For Each cmd in objFolderItem.Verbs
            If len(cmd) <> 0 then CmdList = CmdList & vbcrlf & replace(cmd.name, "&", "") 
        Next
        wscript.echo mid(CmdList, 2)

    'If two arguments do verbs for that item

    ElseIf Ag.count = 2 then
        For Each cmd in objFolderItem.Verbs
            If lcase(replace(cmd, "&", "")) = LCase(Ag(1)) then 
                wscript.echo(Cmd.doit)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    'Properties is special cased. Script has to stay running for Properties dialog to show.
        If Lcase(Ag(1)) = "properties" then
            WSHShell.AppActivate(ObjFolderItem.Name & " Properties")
            msgbox "This message box has to stay open to keep the " & ObjFolderItem.Name & " Properties dialog open."
        End If  
    End If
End If
```

Run without a verb it lists available verbs I dragged a batchfile on it.

```
---------------------------

Windows Script Host

---------------------------

Open

Edit

Print

Run as administrator

Restore previous versions

Cut

Copy

Create shortcut

Delete

Rename

Properties
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Run it without a file to see help.

Lists or runs an explorer verb (right click menu) on a file or folder

```
ShVerb <filename> [verb]
```

Used without a verb it lists the verbs available for the file or folder

Comment: Hi thanks, thats a huge script, do I need to put that in above my code which i posted oringally for it to call the cmd file as admin? I cannot right click and run as admin as I am packaging this up in a self extracting exe. I even tried running th exe as admin, but when it gets to the part of the cmd file which needs top copy a bunch of files to c:\program files x86 folder it gets access deneid

Comment: 7 lines starting `ElseIf Ag.count = 2 then
        For Each cmd in objFolderItem.Verbs
` are the core part.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to add this code at the beginning of your .cmd script to automatically check and get admin rights : [From here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044985/how-can-i-auto-elevate-my-batch-file-so-that-it-requests-from-uac-administrator)

```
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Automatically check & get admin rights
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
@echo off
CLS
ECHO.
ECHO =============================
ECHO Running Admin shell
ECHO =============================

:checkPrivileges
NET FILE 1>NUL 2>NUL
if '%errorlevel%' == '0' ( goto gotPrivileges ) else ( goto getPrivileges )

:getPrivileges
if '%1'=='ELEV' (echo ELEV & shift /1 & goto gotPrivileges)
ECHO.
ECHO **************************************
ECHO Invoking UAC for Privilege Escalation
ECHO **************************************

setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "batchPath=%~0"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
ECHO Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs"
ECHO args = "ELEV " >> "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs"
ECHO For Each strArg in WScript.Arguments >> "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs"
ECHO args = args ^& strArg ^& " "  >> "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs"
ECHO Next >> "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs"
ECHO UAC.ShellExecute "!batchPath!", args, "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs"
"%SystemRoot%\System32\WScript.exe" "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs" %*
exit /B

:gotPrivileges
if '%1'=='ELEV' shift /1
setlocal & pushd .
cd /d "%~dp0"

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::START
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

REM Run shell as admin (example) - put here code as you like
ECHO Arguments: %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
cmd /k
```

For example i have to check some registry Keys as admin , so this code did the trick :

```
@echo off
Title Check Registry Keys by Hackoo 2016
Color 1b
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Automatically check & get admin rights
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
CLS
ECHO.
ECHO =============================
ECHO Running Admin shell
ECHO =============================

:checkPrivileges
NET FILE 1>NUL 2>NUL
if '%errorlevel%' == '0' ( goto gotPrivileges ) else ( goto getPrivileges )

:getPrivileges
if '%1'=='ELEV' (echo ELEV & shift /1 & goto gotPrivileges)
ECHO.
ECHO **************************************
ECHO Invoking UAC for Privilege Escalation
ECHO **************************************

setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "batchPath=%~0"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
ECHO Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs"
ECHO args = "ELEV " >> "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs"
ECHO For Each strArg in WScript.Arguments >> "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs"
ECHO args = args ^& strArg ^& " "  >> "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs"
ECHO Next >> "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs"
ECHO UAC.ShellExecute "!batchPath!", args, "", "runas", 1 >> "% style="color: #448888;">temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs"
"%SystemRoot%\System32\WScript.exe" "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs" %*
exit /B

:gotPrivileges
if '%1'=='ELEV' shift /1
setlocal & pushd .
cd /d "%~dp0"
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::START
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
REM Run shell as admin (example) - put here code as you like
REM ECHO Arguments: %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
Title Check Registry Keys by Hackoo 2016
Set mykey="HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"^
^ "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"^
^ "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon"^
^ "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\LocalSearch\Search Page"^
^ "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\Start Page"^
^ "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options"^
^ "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\system\Shell"^
^ "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders"

Set LogFile=logkey.txt
If Exist %LogFile% Del %LogFile%

For %%K in (%mykey%) Do Call :Check_Key %%K %LogFile%
Start "" %LogFile%
Exit /b

:Check_Key
reg QUERY "%~1" >nul 2>&1
(
  if %errorlevel% equ 0 ( echo "%~1" & reg QUERY "%~1"
    ) else ( echo "%~1" ===^> Not found
  )
) >>%2 2>&1
```

Comment: Why copy and paste an answer from another question instead of voting to close this one as a duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a windows task to run this VBS, and assign it the "run with the highest privileges" flag. Save it under your sysadmin account, and you will be executing it under that security realm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below powershell command at the beginning to make the elevation for current process.

```
(echo "%~0" & PowerShell start """%~0""" -verb RunAs & Exit /B)
```