# Run Link as Administrator

Tags: html

I have a bat file and I can run this file as administrator by right click on it. Now I create a link which calls the bat file on html page. I want to hit the link and run the file as administrator.

The code which calls my file normal way.

```
<a href="C:\Users\c\Desktop\service-restart.bat">Restart DirectDataLink</a>
```

Answer (score -2):

- Adjust the script [(Link)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12264592/8081260) below the line `::START` that needs to run elevated in below posted batch script. For your example: `call service-restart.bat` and save it as `RunElevated.bat`
- Change your link to `<a href="C:\Users\c\Desktop\RunElevated.bat">Restart DirectDataLink</a>`.

The RunElavated will call your batch script and will try to "selfelevate".

Comment: Can you please tell me why i get down-voted for this answer? i have tested this and i can confirm this works.