# To bypass the UAC in cmd.exe

Tags: batch-file, cmd, uac

My query is basically to bypass the "Admin Command Prompt" UAC.

What i am trying to do is to open a "Admin Command Prompt" but every time when i open it pop up UAC, which i want to ignore, i want when i run the "Admin Command Prompt" it will automatically open as Admin without any UAC Pop-up

Is there any way i can do that?

I am thinking to create a batch file which runs and open cmd.exe and pass the UAC pop-up, but i am not sure how to create the same

Tag: "Admin Command Prompt" : It is basically when we right click on cmd.exe and use "Run As Administrator"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I auto-elevate my batch file, so that it requests from UAC administrator rights if required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044985/how-can-i-auto-elevate-my-batch-file-so-that-it-requests-from-uac-administrator)

Comment: Or this one: https://superuser.com/a/1310459/774709

Comment: If it were possible, all malware would do it. Read this first: [FAQ: Why can't I bypass the UAC prompt?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsvistasecurity/2007/08/09/faq-why-cant-i-bypass-the-uac-prompt/)

Comment: UAC **CAN** be bypassed if you are already an **ADMIN**. See [UAC Getting in the Way of EXE Install Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60292423/12861751)

Comment: Which isn't bypassing UAC; it's just addressing it earlier - before you open `cmd`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't bypass. If the user is a standard user, you have no way to arbitrarily decide to just **become** an administrator.

Windows is a secure operating system, and has the notion of standard users and administrators. The fact that you're a standard user is your own choice.

You're perfectly free to ask the computer administrator to make you an administrator - but it's a really, *really*, terrible idea.