# Batch file Proxy Setting Disable not working Win 10

Tags: batch-file

The following line of script from a Batch file works fine in Win 7 and successfully disables the proxy setting in IE, but when i have tried it on Win 10 it dosnt work the proxy setting in unaffected, any ideas why?

UAC is auto elevated as per [UAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044985/how-can-i-auto-elevate-my-batch-file-so-that-it-requests-from-uac-administrator/12264592#12264592) so admin privileges is not an issue.

i have checked with regedit and the HKCU directory seems to be the same path on both.

```
echo LAN Settings - Proxy Setting *Disable*

reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" ^ /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

IE > Internet Options > Connections > LAN Settings

[image]

Comment: Does not work is a horrible explanation to a problem. what does not work? do you see a success message, error or what happens? Please clarify? Also, I think that you should perhaps try run your script with some admin privileges and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Adding something which already exists is the most general error case. Is this such a case? :-)

Comment: The Proxy setting does not disable, there's no error it just does nothing. In Win 7 the IE Proxy setting check box is un-ticked when this is run. UAC auto elevated with code however it also dosnt work when run with admin privileges

Comment: to clarify further the setting this is toggling is IE > Internet Options > Connections > LAN Settings

Comment: @Dominique no this isnt the case:
Win 10 - to test i manually enable proxy in IE settings then run the script, check IE Settings proxy is not disabled  
Win 7 - to test i manually enable proxy in IE settings then run the script, check IE Settings proxy is disabled

Comment: Did you close the `Internet Options` dialog and then reopen it before veryfying whether the check mark had been removed? My verification process in both `Windows 7` and `Windows 10` showed that doing so correctly reflected the state, _leaving the Internet Options dialog open before choosing LAN Settings showed no change_. Also as a side note, the setting is for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` so there's no reason at all to be elevating the command, _you should only need to implement that for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` settings_. Finally, please remove the unnecessary caret, **`^`**, there's nothing to escape.