# How to make an executable file run only run as administrator (UAC icon on the exe)

Tags: exe, uac

I have made a python executable but it fails if not run with administrator. I have other files on my pc that has a UAC icon and when clicked always run as administrator.

Example

[image]

Does anyone know how I can change my python file to achieve this, thank you.

Comment: let a batch script which elevates to start your program, effectively making it the way you like see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7045097/12341099)

Comment: Thats not what i am trying to achieve

Comment: Your executable would have to have an [application manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/application-manifests) with `requireAdministrator` set. With that said, though, why do you require administrator privilege?