# Run batch files with admin rights via Python

Tags: python, windows

**Greetings,**

I want to creat an Windows Optimizer App in python. I`ve created a checkbox and run button.

When the "clear temp" is selected when i press run i want it to run a batch script, stored in the build folder.

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Button, Checkbutton, PhotoImage, IntVar, Entry, Text, messagebox
import os
import subprocess
from pathlib import Path


# ? Add functionality

# * Function to execute a script with admin privileges.
def execute_script_as_admin(script_path):
    # Use the "runas" command to run the script with admin privileges.
    admin_command = f'runas /user:Administrator "cmd /C {script_path}"'
    subprocess.run(admin_command, shell=True)

# * Create a functionality for
# ! "Clear Temp" option

# Function to get the user desktop path


def get_desktop_path():
    return os.path.expanduser("Desktop")


# Define the path to the clear_temp.bat script

clear_temp_script_relative_path = "OptimizationApp\\build\\assets\\IndividualScripts\\GeneralScripts\\clear_temp.bat"

# Create the full script path

clear_temp_script_path = os.path.join(
    get_desktop_path(), clear_temp_script_relative_path)

# Function to run the clear_temp.bat script


def run_clear_temp_script():
    execute_script_as_admin(clear_temp_script_path)


# * Create a functionality for
# ! "Run selected" button

# Function to check which checkboxes are selected and execute the corresponding scripts
def run_selected_scripts():
    if clear_temp_var.get() == 1:
        run_clear_temp_script()
    # TODO Add more conditions for other checkboxes here


# Function to be called when button_2 is clicked


def on_button_2_click():
    if clear_temp_var.get() == 0:
        messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Please select at least one option!")
    else:
        run_selected_scripts()
```

When i run the command it asks for Administrator password, my PC have only one user that`s admin by default with no password selected. Blanks etc are not accepted

How can i run a batch script in that case via python as i will select run as admin from the context menu?

I tried to put the script right inside the code, thinking of running the py app as admin will do the job, i`ve got the confirmation message but no actions were taken.

I know there is another way to clear temp that it works

```
def clean_temp_files():
    username = getpass.getuser()
    folder_path = f"C:\\Users\\{username}\\AppData\\Local\\Temp"
    system_path = "C:\\Windows\\Temp"

    # Delete for logged user
    try:
        for item in os.listdir(folder_path):
            item_path = os.path.join(folder_path, item)
            try:
                if os.path.isfile(item_path):
                    os.remove(item_path)
                elif os.path.isdir(item_path):
                    shutil.rmtree(item_path)
            except (PermissionError, FileNotFoundError) as e:
                print(f"Skipped {item_path} due to error: {e}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Action Failed: {e}")

    # Delete for System
    try:
        for item in os.listdir(system_path):
            item_path = os.path.join(system_path, item)
            try:
                if os.path.isfile(item_path):
                    os.remove(item_path)
                elif os.path.isdir(item_path):
                    shutil.rmtree(item_path)
            except (PermissionError, FileNotFoundError) as e:
                print(f"Skipped {item_path} due to error: {e}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Action Failed: {e}")
```

But as a begginer it's easier for me to call premade individual scripts. And some batch scripts requires admin rights to run. I use clear temp as example, but i`m sure once i find a solutin i can expand it

I`ve looked after some responses in similar topic, but what i find it's quite old.

Here is the entire code in needed https://github.com/mcata97/windows-optimizer-app

In the end i want to make an executable out of this to use when needed

PS: I know the internet is full of tools that can do the job done, but i want to try it to do it myself to see if i`m attracted to this "culture" i will want also to use it on another pc's

Thanks for your time in advance !

Answer (score 1):

One fix that might work could be to have the batch script elevate itself using UAC here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044985/how-can-i-auto-elevate-my-batch-file-so-that-it-requests-from-uac-administrator)

or you could also just add an admin password if the script is only for self use (I would probably have one anyways for security)

or (probably the way you want) you can use ctypes with runas to ask for a UAC prompt and run a command as admin but im not sure how to hide the cmd window if thats a problem:

```
import ctypes

commands = u'/k echo Hello' # replace echo Hello with your command
ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(
        None,
        u"runas",
        u"cmd.exe",
        commands,
        None,
        1
    )
input() # this is here to stop the program from just exiting causing the cmd to close
```

Comment: you can also check if your python program is being ran by a user with admin:  ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()

Comment: if you want the window minimized instead you can change the value from 1  to 2 and for maximized 3

Comment: here is a nice website I found that shows the uses of ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW:   https://www.sourceinsight.com/doc/v3/ag923048.htm

Comment: Greetings, thanks for asnwer, i will try both. One question tho.. if i try to elevate the batch itself if i run multiple scripts will generate a high load checking everytime ? or it will run a scrip one by one ?